# ASP.NET Core Identity, Azure SQL database backups, and GDPR data deletion requests

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-sql-database, database-backups

To comply with GDPR regulation, a user must be able to request deletion of all its data.

Just deleting an account from a database is easy, but we are using Microsoft Azure SQL server, with automatic backups. We use asp.net core identity with individual accounts.

So obviously user data will not be deleted from these backups.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

It seems Active Directory provides GDPR tools, but we are not using that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-3.0),

> ASP.NET Core provides APIs and templates to help meet some of the EU
>   General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR)

ASP.NET Core apps created with individual user accounts include code to download and [`delete personal data`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/gdpr.md#pd).

Comment: Thanks. But as far as I can tell, this doesn't delete the user from back-ups?

Comment: Okay. But in the case of automatic SQL backups in Azure (these can be restored to milliseconds time in the past), this doesn't seem to be obvious?